# Is it possible to convert my timeline (adobe flash) with all its child to TimelineMax (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I using the default timeline because the animation is too hard if I animate it using TweenMax (AS3). Now I need to convert it too TimelineMax, because its more flexible in manipulating it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually, it could take time.. Flash is just an xml type file with animations applied in a visual way using timeline... you can get the same results using the Tween engines with out the visual timeline...generally tweening classes perform heaps better due to distance over time, opposed to frame rates, and key animations which can become heavy.

If you provided a link to your animation it could be easier to understand more-or-less the approach you should take.